# NullPointerException for EntityManager using @PersistenceContext

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-entitymanager

I'm trying to create an auditing service that has an `EntityManager`. However, this `EntityManager` is never initialized when I run the application, so when calling it, it throws a `NullPointerException`.

My code looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;


@Service
public class AuditServiceImpl implements AuditService {

    private static final String FULL_NAME = "%s %s";

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager(){
        return entityManager;
    }
}
```

I expected that the `@PersistenceContext` annotation would fix this for me, but it did not. I saw several other posts about similar problems, but most solutions seem outdated, so I decided to create another post.

Can anybody shed some light on the problem, maybe even a solution?

Comment: How are you creating the `AuditServiceImpl` instance?

Comment: I use the default constructor for that.

Comment: And how do you expect Spring to inject dependencies into a bean instance it doesn't know? If you create instances yourself no dependencies will be injected.

Comment: If I let Spring create it by using the annotation @ PersistenceContext or @ PersistenceUnit (At this point I'm lost in these annotations) it still gives the NullPointerException..

Comment: Then you have a wrong configuration. First thing never create instances yourself, use dependency injectio. If you need a `AuditService` inject it, don't create it. Make sure you have a `<context:component-scan />` if using XML or (`@ComponentScan` when using java config). If you have those and you also have Spring manage your entity manager it will be injected. if not you are really missing things. I strongly suggest a read of the reference guide on how to inject an `EntityManager` or `EntityManagerFactory` and the difference between the 2.

Comment: Thank you, you were right. The solution was to keep the logics inside the AuditServiceImpl, this way I can use the EntityManager inside the class, instead of what I was trying to do; inside a DTO.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please ensure the EntityManagerFactory and persistence unit are set up properly. A simple XML style will be like:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="..." />
<bean id="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="yourPersistenceUnit" />
</bean>
```

But from your comment down below the question looks like how the AuditServiceImpl is referenced might be the cause. Basically the client who uses AuditService should get the reference from Spring IoC container rather than instantiate the object itself. It can be done in various way, like using ApplicationContext if you instantiate the container in standalone application through XML style:

```
ApplicationContext context =
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"yourApplicationContext.xml"});
AuditService auditService = context.getBean("auditService", AuditService.class);
auditService.doSomething();
```

Or inject the service into client at the web layer if you are using Spring MVC.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    AuditService auditService;

    public void foo() {
        auditService.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of injecting EntityManager, inject EntityManagerFactory in the code

Please see below:

`@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "persistanceUnitName")
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;`

And then for getting EntityManager,Please execute below code:

`public EntityManager getEntityManager(){
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }`

Comment: Thank you, but it still gives a NullPointerException for 
return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

Comment: Please check whether persistanceUnitName has been properly specified in persistance.xml file.

Comment: I do not use the persistence.xml file since I use annotations.

Comment: in a controller class like MyController i would not advice to inject the EntityManagerFactory.